# Will using Typescript over Javascript for NodeJS lambda increases Cold Start Time?

Tags: aws-lambda

With Node JS Lambda runtime, if we move from Javascript language to Typescript language, will that affect the cold start time?

Answer (score 0):

No, any way you need to "compile" the TS Before uploading to AWS.